# How do I jump to the method that will be run in Intellij-IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a keyboard shortcut I can use to jump to the method that would get run if I clicked the run button?

[image]

In this case, how can I jump my keyboard cursor to `JustATest.testName()`?

Comment: The only known entrypoint is the `main` method (assuming this is a project that even has an explicit entrypoint), anything beyond that would require you to run the program since there is no feasible way to statically determine a program's execution.

Comment: I'm sorry, I asked my question poorly.  See my edit re: "by clicking the "green" play button at the top".

Comment: The point still stands I believe: the IDE cannot know the order of execution without running it.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I find that so strange.  If I rename a method manually (i.e., w/o a "refactoring") that dropdown at the top immediately knows that it no longer points to a valid method and puts an x icon by it.  If it can know that much, why can't it know which method to jump to?

Comment: Static analysis of a class that isn't being executed is straightforward; keep track of all of the symbols.  Doing the same for a class that *is* being executed is nigh impossible, since again - you can't guarantee if/when that method will be called.

Comment: My comments refers to the fact that execution order of methods cannot be determined without running the code. That implies that there are no buttons in your IDE to jump between methods simply because it is impossible. The only exception for this is the entrypoint: every program knows its entrypoint.

Comment: Check out my edit.  Hopefully the way I worded the question now is more clear.  Are we still on the same page?  I'm sorry it was so unclear initially.  That is completely my fault.

Comment: It's not that you're not being clear, at this point.  IntelliJ just doesn't support that when you click the run button for the reasons that have been elaborated on above.  The solution in my answer can *help*, since it relies more on static analysis rather than the dynamic aspect.  Again, you can't guarantee that this method is going to be executed; any manner of exceptions could occur between the actual program's entry point and the execution of that method.

Comment: @Makoto gotcha, just wanted to make sure.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can jump to a specific method or field by adding a pound character (#) when you do a class search.

Depending on your keyboard setup, a class search is done with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

So, you'd want to type in the pop-up dialog `TestClassTest#testMethod`, and it will take your cursor straight to it.  There *might* be a bit of shakiness with split panes, but for the most part, this is a simple solution that works in the general case.

The other way involves placing a [bookmark](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/managing-bookmarks.html) on that line of code, and recalling it either through the Favorites bar or through the provided shortcuts.

Outside of that, you don't have many other options.  IntelliJ wouldn't be able to divine that this method will for sure be run, since any manner of exceptions could occur before it gets to that method.  At that point, you're left with just breakpoints in your code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I asked my question poorly.  See my edit re: "by clicking the "green" play button at the top".

Comment: In that regard, I defer to Jeroen's comment.  IntelliJ isn't capable of divining where and when a method is going to be run, but you're capable of setting a breakpoint on the desired method or using the above method.